How to Generate PDF Thumbnails for Frontend Display in a Next.js + Sanity Application?
I am building an application using Next.js and Sanity, where users can upload PDFs via Sanity. On the frontend, I want to display these PDFs as thumbnails (just the front page of the PDF is enough). Users should be able to click on the thumbnail to either view the full PDF in a viewer or download it.
I’ve successfully set up the Sanity backend for uploading and retrieving PDFs. However, I’m struggling to find a library or approach that can generate thumbnails from PDFs to display them on the frontend.
Requirements:
Generate a thumbnail (first page) of the PDF.
Display the thumbnail on the frontend.
On click, open the full PDF for viewing or downloading.

I’ve searched for libraries but can’t find a suitable one to generate thumbnails efficiently. Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Here is an example of the JSON object returned for each PDF:
{
  "_id": "887ec5b8-0145-458d-825a-6d405f60532f",
  "pdfTitle": "PDF 2024",
  "pdfFile": {
    "asset": {
      "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    }
  }
}


@KJ Thanks for your input, but I think there’s a bit of confusion about what I’m trying to achieve. Let me clarify:
I already have a system implemented using Sanity where users can upload PDFs, and these PDFs are successfully displayed on a webpage.
What I want to do now is enhance this by generating a thumbnail (an image) of the first page of the PDF. This thumbnail will replace the current PDF name displayed on the webpage.
When users click on the thumbnail, it will still open the full PDF, just as it does now.


@KJ I just updated the question with what json object I get back.
